# Reactjs multiline ellipsis npm plugin issue

Tags: reactjs, ellipsis

I am trying to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-lines-ellipsis component and it is not working for me as expected or I just cant figure out this docs. It is truncating my text but it does not expand it when I clink on 'Read more' as you can see it in the demo.
https://xiaody.github.io/react-lines-ellipsis/

Here is my code, please anyone point out what I missed. Thanks
https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-jennings-55u4y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really documentation is unclear. This library just hides a text. It has not handlers. You should implement yourself.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import LinesEllipsis from "react-lines-ellipsis";

function App() {
 const longText =
 "lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
   lorem loremlorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem 
    lorem lorem lorem lorem";
 const [isExpand, setExpand] = useState(false);
 return (
  <div className="App">
   {isExpand ? (
    <div>{longText}</div>
   ) : (
    <div onClick={() => setExpand(!isExpand)}>
      <LinesEllipsis text={longText} maxLine="1" ellipsis="... Read more" />
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```

);
 }

Comment: @EdvardsNiedre pls check my answer ;)

Comment: Ahh, cool. Sure thing. Didn't know you can do this here. Check! :)